# Multitail: how to view whole file?

Tags: linux, logging

I have a big log file (10000 lines). When I open it with [multital](http://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail)  only last ~100 lines are loaded, so I can't scroll back and view another preexisting lines.

Doesn't work because affect only on new lines appeared after file opening:

- -m nlines
- -mb x
- -M nlines

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've solve it with piping.

```
tail -n 1000 -f myfile.log | multitail -j
```

Answer (score 1):

`man multitail` says following:

> **-n** number_of_lines
>
> Number of lines to tail initially. The default depends on the size of the terminal-window.

So you could do:

```
multitail -n 2000 /path/to/file
```

to load 2000 line to initial buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the free [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: This is not an answer to OP. In addition the suggested program is now deprecated, not to mention only for OS X and not for free!